# Non-reviewable item

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

Just wanted to ask what a non-reviewable item is?

I noticed it just now while checking suggested-edits section.

The link is https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1964962

**EDIT** Found another one of this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1995373

Is it some old audit that another user passed and it was still served to me?

[image: img]

Answer (score 8):

To answer your direct question: A review item gets marked as not reviewable when the conditions for its creation no longer apply. For example, if a post gets deleted when it was in a review queue, the review item is not destroyed, it's just no longer reviewable (however, not complete). Or if a question gets closed *outside* of the Close Votes review queue, review does not complete, but the item becomes unreviewable.

Review items that are no longer reviewable are not supposed to get served to users. I have no idea why you would have been shown that one. It could be possible that a user Skipping a review audit doesn't cause it to become immediately unreviewable and you were just unlucky and attempted to load one in that tiny timeframe.

**Update:** It's now been reviewed, so it could have been a race condition for the audit. A dev will have to explain what exactly happens with review audits.