# What would cause an item to be classified as "not reviewable"?

Tags: support, review

There are a number of times when I've seen a

> This item is not reviewable.

clause when processing some items in the review queues when it is clearly still being reviewed by others; a refresh of the page lists updated reviews by community members, yet I'm just not able to do the same. This has happened across no specific review queue, and there is no explanation as to why this happens - like someone slammed a door in your face, and you're left standing outside watching everyone inside enjoy pizza and beer... yes, review queues are fun...?

What could cause this? Is it queue dependent?

Similar questions that don't answer this one (since they seem review-audit related, or review-queue dependent):

- [Clarify “This item is not reviewable” message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163558/168244)
- [“Item is not reviewable” when migrating a question in the close queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211351/168244)
- [Non-reviewable item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177382/168244)

---

One hint as to how/why this happens which is clearly unrelated to a review-audit:

1. I [flagged a post as "not an answer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCZ9n.png);
2. Perhaps another user flagged it as "low quality", making it end up in the Low Quality Post review queue. I ended up seeing this:

   [image]
3. The second vote-to-close was made by a mod (after seeing and responding to a/the flag), but that doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: Do you have links to a specific review that this happened on? Nearly every time I've run into it, it's because it's a review audit that I left alone too long.

Comment: @StevenV: This wouldn't help as of now, since the review item that spawned this question was completed by other users, with the "This item is not reviewable" message being replaced by a "**Review completed X ago**". I'll post a screenshot the next time this occurs.

Comment: Did you already cast a delete vote on the answer in question?

Comment: @hichris123: No. I just monitored the Low Quality Post review queue at the time to show that the "item is not reviewable" *to me*, but reviewable to others.