# Strange behaviour in close vote review audit ("This item is not available for review")

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close, review-audits

I've done the most close (and re-open) reviewing on Server Fault.

Interestingly, the odd behaviour I've run into recently only shows up because I'm *not* a robo-reviewer:

- In many cases, if it's not clear to me that a question is bad and deserves to be closed, I click on the question title in the review screen and look at the actual question, answers, and comments.  Then I click back and pick the appropriate review button.
- Since many audits are odd-looking in the review screen (they seem awful but show upvotes, or seem good and have downvotes), I often look at the real question, and it's revealed as an audit because the votes are different or some other giveaway

Recently (noticed it today, pretty sure it's happened in the past few days, but I don't think it happened 2 weeks ago and before), when I click on an odd question, see that it's an audit, then click back, I get a message

> This item is not available for review.

Today, I kept getting the same audit, clicked on it twice, got the above message, but the 3rd time I just picked "close" and got the "Congratulations!" message.

I'm going to tag this as a bug, because I'm sure it's not how reviews worked before, and certainly if someone is diligent enough to go look at the question, they aren't a robo-reviewer and should be able to review the audit at that point.

About a month later, this is still happening, today it's been different questions each time.  It's *not* anything to do with the question getting closed right as I review it, as this capture shows:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

This question was closed a month ago, is showing up now as a review audit, but if I go and look at the question, then go back, it's no longer considered a review.  If anything, looking at the question should be considered a "pass," but it should at least *let* me review it.

Comment: Not sure why this would be happening, other than the question already was closed in the meantime? So it wouldn't be eligible for reviewing anymore? I have noticed the back button being borked in some other cases, but not for this issue.

Comment: @lostsock But if the question was an audit, it would't be actually under review (or being closed meantime).

Comment: If you open a question/answer in the same tab you often loose the chance to review it again, even if it's not an audit. So open them in a new tab instead.

Comment: @Curiousdannii this rarely happens with normal questions (certainly not "often" for me) but it's happening most of the time now for audits.

Comment: @Ward Oh I hadn't noticed it was you who asked this. I'm sure you've got more review experience than most people, so if you think something's odd then it probably is!

Comment: I first observed this behavior about a month ago at Programmers. After this, I _always_ use new (separate) tab/window to open the reviewed post, so that review stays where it was

Comment: Related: [What would cause an item to be classified as “not reviewable”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231763/168244)